# Getting 'error expected end of statements' in qlikview macro

Tags: vba, macros, qlikview

```
function fAdd()
dim x As Integer
dim y As Integer
fAdd=x+y
end function
```

When I try to run this code, getting error saying 'expected end of statements' with As Integer at the first line being highlighted.

Comment: This code compiles just fine. This issue cannot be reproduced.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know qlikview so I can only say that:

- your code doesn't throw error in VBA
- may be you wanted to code

  ```
  Function fAdd(x As Integer, y As Integer)
      fAdd = x + y
  End Function
  ```

  where your `fAdd()` function would accept two arguments (`x` and `y`) of `Integer` type and return their sum

Answer (score 0):

your function should look like below. However this function will always return 0 as x and y are initialized by default to 0.

```
function fAdd() 
 dim x As Integer 
 dim y As Integer 
 fAdd=x+y 
end function
```

Comment: "should look like below" <-- looks identical to what's in the question?